# How to make a $4\times 4$ matrix each of $i$-th row and $i$-th column having all the elements $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$?

Tags: matrices, puzzle

This question was asked as a puzzle in one Book of Puzzles by RS AGGARWAL, which stated the problem as to build an order N matrix where each i'th row and i'th column
combined have all the elements from 1 to 2N-1.

For instance, for N=2

> [3,2]
>   [1,3]

I want to know when is an answer possible for it for which values of N it is possible to make a matrix and how to make it?

Comment: {{1,2,3,4}, {5 1 7 6}, {6 4 1 5}, {7 3 2 1}} Is this a solution for N=4?

Comment: yes! this fits as a solution but how to deduce it ?  Please explain me how to find this for any N*N matrix

Comment: Just Luck. I was trying to understand the problem. My idea is to put the same number at the diagonal and try to fill the gaps. Like a SuDoKu

Comment: This is a duplicate of a now deleted earlier question. The only thing that emerged [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501453/placing-numbers-in-a-matrix-with-constraints?) was that it is easy to see it is impossible for $n$ odd, and that there is probably a way of doing it for all (even) $2^n$. All the solutions there put one number all down the main diagonal and filled the triangle above the diagonal with one set of $n-1$ numbers and the triangle below with the remaining $n-1$ numbers.